# CKFinder 5 integration with Image plugin

Tags: ckeditor5, ckfinder, ckeditor4

CKEditor4's image upload has a "Browse Server" option, and when clicked, it integrates with CKFinder to let the user pick images from the file library.
An example is at https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/demo/#document (attached recording of the behavior below)
[image: CKEditor4 Image Upload Behavior]

I've not been able to find similar functionality in CKEditor5. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for exactly the same "Browse Server" button (and an Image dialog) in CKEditor 5 or are you looking for the functionality to "browse server" and insert/reuse images using a file manager?

CKEditor 5 comes with two solutions that provide this functionality:

**CKFinder**

- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/file-management/ckfinder.html#full-integration

**CKBox**

- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/file-management/ckbox.html#demo
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckbox/latest/features/index.html

(You may expect CKBox to come up with new features soon, such as: private files, workspaces and image editing)

Due to how the CKEditor 5 image feature has been implemented, opening "file managers" is available done via a separate, dedicated toolbar button.

Could you let me know if this is what you are looking for? Or would you like it to be available in a different way? If yes, then could you elaborate on why?

Comment: I am looking for the same/exact "Browse Server" functionality @wiktor-walc